# How I can use the mysql jdbc driver deployed inside a war spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, web-deployment

I created a spring boot application using JPA and mysql. When I deploy the application as a jar file all works fine. If I deploy the application as a war file on tomcat 8.0 as requested by my customer, the application is unable to locate jdbc driver unless I put it inside TOMCAT_HOME/lib directory. My customer doesn't what to put driver into TOMCAT_HOME/lib. I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    ... 65 more
```

Is there a way to make tomcat refer to the jdbc driver located into the war file?
My pom.xml file has the following dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>   


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are configuring the datasource yourself. let Spring Boot do this for you. Also the `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't really meant to be used in production as it isn't a connection pool. So ditch your `DataSource` bean definition (remove the `@Bean` method) and add the required `spring.datasource.*` properties to `application.properties` and restart your application.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the error came from. I Initialized manually the datasource without specifying the driver class

```
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
```

the code that works is:

```
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSource;
```